# Скрипт python 2.7

Tags: python

Есть обширный скрипт на python 2.7 с кучей библиотек. Необходимо научить его запускаться на RedHat 4ES. Там по умолчанию python2.3. Возможно ли упаковать скрипт с окружением и перенести папку на машину с RedHat?

Comment: Может быть посмотреть в сторону Docker. Он как раз позволяет создавать легковесные изолированные окружения.  Еще один вариант - virtualenv.

Comment: Думаю лучше сначала попробовать поставить с использованием virtualenv.

Comment: @demas, если там действительно redhat четвертой версии, то скорее всего ядро не потянет (а так, конечно, докер именно для этого и создавался).

Answer (score 3):

Это возможно. 
Для этого Вам понадобится собрать (отдельная тема) rpm-пакет python-2.7 и установить его с ключем --prefix, например:

```
rpm -ivh --prefix=/opt/python27 python27*.rpm
```

Это позволит использовать в скрипте эту версию python, используя новый shebang
для скриптов, например:

```
#!/opt/python27/usr/bin/python
```

Другой путь - использовать installation manager, для python это, например, [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz).

Comment: Не факт что это сработает. Там стоит gcc 3.4, может не взлететь

Answer (score 2):

Я бы попробовал сделать standalone приложение с помощью Nuitka или его аналогов

Answer (score 1):

Если скрипт использует только модули python, самое простое это использовать `virtualenv`.

Создайте virtualenv для вашего скрипта, установите в него необходимые модули,
запускайте скрипт python-ом из виртуального окружения virtualenv.

Пример:

```
mkdir -p my-script/bin
cd my-script
cp /path/to/my-script.py bin/
virtualenv ve
ve/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
ve/bin/python bin/my-script.py
```

Предполагается, что в файле requirements.txt перечислены ваши зависимости.

Comment: На RH4ES нет virtualenv. Возможно ли просто взять каталог с созданным venv и перенести? Конечно использовать python из  venv

Comment: @kaffka: да, но только пути должны сохраниться и версия python тоже

Comment: если есть `python2.7` исполняемый файл, то можно просто [скачать архив и запустить: `python virtualenv.py ve`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html). Это создаст `ve` окружение внутри которого есть `pip` с помощью которого можно всё остальное поставить -- *это никак не поможет с компиляцией С зависимостей*. Если свежий `python2.7` доступен, то `pip` уже включён и можно выполнить: `python2.7 -mensurepip -U`; `python2.7 -mpip install --user virtualenv`, чтобы текущему пользователю `virtualenv` стал доступен (возможно путь подправить надо, чтобы `~/.local/bin` содержал).

Answer (score 1):

Большая часть библиотек python2.3 совместима с python2.7, соответственно с большой долей вероятности скрипт запустится. 
Совершенно иной вопрос, это установка библиотек. Если используется много нестандартных библиотек и их версий, то вероятно имеет смысл создание собственного окружения для этого скрипта с помощью virtualenv.

Comment: Очень маловероятно, что нетривиальный скрипт для 2.7, запустится на 2.3. Например, `virtualenv` уже не поддерживает Python 2.3, значит придётся использовать старую версию или даже самостоятельно адаптировать под 2.3.